# How do I execute multiple firebase uploads and wait for the collective results

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I am playing around with Firebase Storage baked into an photo collection app that takes a collection of photos and uploads them to a firebase storage backend. I want to upload multiple photos and wait for all tasks to finish, collect the download urls and proceed to the next step. Here is my code below

```
    public void saveImageData() {
    Incident incident = new Incident();
    final ArrayList<Uri> downloadUris = new ArrayList<>();

    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);
    for (Uri uri : imageUris) {
        StorageReference imagesRef = storageRef.child("images/" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        uploadTask = imagesRef.putFile(uri);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                downloadUris.add(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());
                Log.e(TAG, "Size of data: " + downloadUris.size());
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I would like for all the uris to be collected and use the results stored in downloadUris. As I type this I realise this may not be a firebase issue but understanding how to wait for parallel tasks to finish executing and proceed with the results. How can I achieve this objective?
Thanks

Comment: Did the proposed answer help your situation?

Answer (score 9):

The [Play services Task API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) actually powers much of the Firebase client side asynchronous APIs, such as Firebase Storage file uploads.  That UploadTask you have is a subclass of the standard [Task](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) that accepts success and failure listeners, as you're doing it now.

If you're dealing with multiple concurrent uploads and wish to know when all of them are complete, you can use the [Tasks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks) utility class which has a [whenAll()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) method that accepts multiple Task objects.  That method will return a new Task where you can register additional success and failure listeners.  The success listener will be called as soon as all the Tasks are complete, and the failure listener will be called if and when *any* of the tasks fail.

You can register listeners both on the individual tasks, and also on the composite task returned from Tasks.whenAll().

(Also, stay tuned of an [upcoming blog series](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html) about the use of the Task API with various Firebase features.)